# iCalendar (RFC5545) recurrence rule for year

Tags: icalendar, recurrence, rfc2445, rfc5545

How can I make an event occur every year for some selected days, Like starting 45 days then skip 15 days, then select 30 days then skip 30 days, then select 30 days then skip 30 days, then select 30 days then skip 30 days,then select 30 days then skip 30 days,then select 30 days then skip 30 days

```
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYYEARDAY=1,2,..,45,61,62,...,90,120,121....
```

Is this the right procedure?

Answer (score 0):

combination of freq=yearly and byyearday is indeed the way forward, though it does not look ot be the case for you, you could also consider BYWEEKNO.